# Problem with babel-esLint: Parsing error: require() of ES Module

Tags: babeljs, eslint

**Hello. I need your help. How can I fix this error?**

Parsing error: require() of ES Module Desktop/Projects/MealsToGo/node_modules/eslint-scope/lib/definition.js from Desktop/Projects/MealsToGo/node_modules/babel-eslint/lib/require-from-eslint.js not supported.
Instead change the require of definition.js in Desktop/Projects/MealsToGo/node_modules/babel-eslint/lib/require-from-eslint.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules

Answer (score 95):

This is probably happening because you, like me, were using the old babel parser. Package [`babel-eslint`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-eslint) has been deprecated since March of 2020.
The package was migrated to new repo, if you want to know more, I recommend you check [Babel](https://github.com/babel/babel) git.

Just change and install or update to the latest parser packaged in `.eslintrc.js`:

**Old .eslintrc.js:**

```js
module.exports = {
  parser: 'babel-eslint',
  ...
};
```

**New .eslintrc.js**

```js
module.exports = {
   parser: '@babel/eslint-parser',
   ...
};
```

Comment: I inherited a similar project with this issue. In case it helps someone else, the configuration changes I had to make were all in package.json: update package from `babel-eslit` to `@babel/eslint-parser` and then update the `eslintConfig` > `parserOptions` > `parser` setting to `@babel/eslint-parser` as well.

Answer (score 3):

The solution that works for me was: In the .eslintrc file Just change:

```rc
"parser": 'babel-eslint'
```

to:

```rc
"parser": '@babel/eslint-parser'
```

Comment: Seems identical to [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70458446/6243352).

Answer (score 2):

Another cause of this issue is an old node version.

I was getting this with ESLint 8.10.0 and Node 12. Upgrading Node to 14 was the fix.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:
module.exports = {
parser: '@babel/eslint-parser',
...
};

Comment: Seems identical to [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70458446/6243352).

Answer (score 0):

For me, using a .json file rather than a .js file for .eslintrc allowed `eslint .` to operate as it should in a module-based project.

Failed attempts (.eslintrc.js):

```js
export default {
// also tried: export {
// also tried: module.exports = {
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "extends": "eslint:recommended",
  "overrides": [
    {
      "env": {
        "node": true
      },
      "files": [
        ".eslintrc.{js,cjs}"
      ],
      "parserOptions": {
        "sourceType": "script"
      }
    }
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "rules": {
  }
}
```

All of the above trigger:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /path/to/.eslintrc.js from /home/me/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.1/lib/node_modules/eslint/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/dist/eslintrc.cjs not supported.

.eslintrc.js is treated as an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which declares all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead either rename .eslintrc.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules, or change "type": "module" to "type": "commonjs" in /path/to/package.json to treat all .js files as CommonJS (using .mjs for all ES modules instead).
```

Correct version (rename to .eslintrc.json, remove the `export` syntax and ensure valid JSON):

```json
{
  "env": {
  // ... same content above onward ...
}
```

package.json:

```json
{
  "type": "module",
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.57.0"
  }
}
```

As the above error message indicates, rather than switching to JSON, another option is to keep the `module.exports = { ... }` syntax but rename .eslintrc.js to .eslintrc.cjs.

Removing `"type": "module"` from the package.json and using CJS is also possible, but my project is entirely modules, so I'd have to rename a ton of .js files to .mjs if I used this approach.

[The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70458446/6243352) didn't seem to make a difference in my case.