# Heroku fail to compile: [eslint] Must use import to load ES Module

Tags: node.js, npm, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a react app I worked on and when I try to push to heroku master it says "failed to compile node.js". Now I've already tried to specify what node I'm using and update to the lastest parser [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69554485/eslint-error-must-use-import-to-load-es-module), but still getting an error.

Here is what I'm getting in the terminal:

```
-----> Build
       Running heroku-postbuild
       
       > potato-network@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_82788311
       > cd client && npm install && npm run build
       
       
       > core-js@3.25.4 postinstall /tmp/build_82788311/client/node_modules/core-js
       > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
       
       
       > core-js-pure@3.25.4 postinstall /tmp/build_82788311/client/node_modules/core-js-pure
       > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
       
       added 1429 packages from 795 contributors and audited 1434 packages in 21.79s
       
       211 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       found 1 high severity vulnerability
         run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
       
       > client@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_82788311/client
       > react-scripts build
       
       Creating an optimized production build...
       Failed to compile.
       
       [eslint] Must use import to load ES Module: /tmp/build_82788311/client/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/universal.js
       require() of ES modules is not supported.
       require() of /tmp/build_82788311/client/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/universal.js from /tmp/build_82788311/client/node_modules/eslint/lib/linter/linter.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
       Instead rename universal.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from /tmp/build_82788311/client/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/package.json.
       
       
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! client@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.h5MIg/_logs/2022-10-03T00_22_02_904Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! potato-network@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `cd client && npm install && npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the potato-network@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.h5MIg/_logs/2022-10-03T00_22_02_911Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
```

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "peerjs": "^1.3.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-share": "^4.3.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^3.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.5.4",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.2",
    "eslint": "^8.24.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is my .eslinct.js:

```
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  parser: "@babel/eslint-parser",
  extends: ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended"],
  overrides: [],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: "latest",
    requireConfigFile: false,
    sourceType: "module",
  },
  plugins: ["react"],
  rules: {},
```

How can I fix it? Googling the error does not present any useful forums or raised bugs.

Comment: add "type": "module" in your pacakage.json file

Comment: check this link as well, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70386909/problem-with-babel-eslint-parsing-error-require-of-es-module

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with babel-esLint: Parsing error: require() of ES Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70386909/problem-with-babel-eslint-parsing-error-require-of-es-module)